# Django ORM. How to save() new value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

How to save() new value?

**Error:**  AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

I have this code:

```
class Magazin(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_magazin', verbose_name='Owner')
    name = models.CharField("Magazin_Name", max_length=30)
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='MagazinProduct', blank=True, null=True)

class MagazinProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    magazin = models.ForeignKey('Magazin')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I try something like this:

```
from magazin.product.models import *

In [2]: user = 2 #user id

In [3]: quantity = 4

In [4]: magazin = Magazin.objects.get(owner=user)

In [6]: mp = MagazinProduct.objects.get(magazin=magazin, product=1) #product=1 this is ID

In [8]: mp.quantity
Out[8]: 1

In  [9]: mp.quantity = quantity
In [10]: mp.quantity
Out[10]: 4

In [11]: mp.quantity.save()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change to:

```
mp.save()
```

instead.

---

`mp` is an instance of `MagzinProduct` class, and `mp.quantity` is just an `int` which doesn't have a `save` method. To update an instance, you call `save()` on this instance, and in this case it is simply `mp.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't save an **attribute** - you save an **instance**. In your example you call save method on `mp` instance like `mp.save()` which would save all the attributes of that object. See [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) for reference.